# Tree structures in document become smaller in poster

Tags: posters

I'm currently using the package `xyling` (I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links, so please use Google to reasearch about this package) to draw tree structures in TeX. This works well in a generic paper:

[image: Tree structure in paper]

However, it looks horrific, when I try to put it in a poster:

[image: Tree structure in poster column]

The tree structure is in the 3rd out of 4 columns. I am using the Jacobs landscape poster in latextemplates.com.

Here are the packages I am using in my paper if it's relevant:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{attrib}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{cgloss}
\bibliographystyle{unified}
```

And here are the ones I'm using in my poster:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70}
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10}
\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in}
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth}
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth}
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth}
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{attrib}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{cgloss}
\bibliographystyle{unified}
```

Please let me know if more information is needed, and thank you for the help.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide code we can compile to reproduce the problem. Right now, we've got a couple of fragments which probably include a bunch of irrelevant stuff (like stuff for a bibliography and custom colours) and certainly exclude crucial stuff (like the tree and the `document` environment).

Answer (score 1):

If another package is an option, a Forest tree will work fine. Here's your tree in Forest (left) and an example from the `xyling` manual (right).

Since you didn't provide usable code, this is a bit hit-and-miss. I don't have the theme you're using and I dropped some packages which seemed irrelevant to the problem.

I think for the `xyling` tree you need to adjust its spacing as the manual says that the size of nodes, for example, does not depend on the content. I think it must be using dimensions such that the node content is scaled by the poster package, but `xyling` doesn't take account of that. It probably goes by the default document font or something of that kind. (Since this is Beamer, that is `11pt`.)

[image: Forest vs. xyling]

The nice thing about the Forest approach is that you could use the same specification directly in your paper and the poster and the sizing should just work, whereas it looks as though you will need to either figure out a general adaption for `xyling` or adjust the code for the trees themselves. (Probably the former is possible and obviously it's better, but I don't know the package.)

You can use e.g. `\Treek[4]{4}` in place of `\Tree`, but it doesn't completely solve the problem. It does help a bit.

[image: slightly better]

You can achieve a similar, partial improvement by adding the following to your preamble, which prevents having to switch the specification of the trees. (That is, you don't have to change to `\Treek` or whatever.)

```
\renewcommand{\Tree}[2][0]{\raisebox{1.24ex}{\xymatrix @H=4pc @W=6pc @R=3pc @C=#1pc {#2}}}
```

Note that I have no idea if this might have unwanted side-effects, but it seems to work on my simple-from-the-manual example to improve spacing a bit.

[image: partial improvement]

Note that the loss of lines is just because I haven't messed around to get them working, since that's not the point of the question. (For anyone interested, the manual explains the whys and the wherefores.)

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{xyling}
\renewcommand{\Tree}[2][0]{\raisebox{1.24ex}{\xymatrix @H=4pc @W=6pc @R=3pc @C=#1pc {#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [DP
    [D'
      [D
        [this]
      ]
      [DP
        [DP
          [our\\biz, roof]
        ]
        [D'
          [DP
            [gen]
          ]
          [NP
            [dog\\kopek, roof]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\Tree{ && \K[5.2]{S}\Bkk{5.2,0}{0,0}{dl}
\Bkk{5.2,0}{0,0}{drr}
 \\
&\NP\TRi &&
 &
 \VP
 \\
& \K{\emph{my beloved}}\Below{\emph{wife}} &&
\Vzero &&
 \NP\TRi[2]
 \\
&&& \T{likes} && \K{\emph{our old house}}
}
\end{document}
```